# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main // What is wrong?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, javac, nosuchmethoderror

I have the following simple code :

```
public class Date
{
 byte day;
 byte month;
 short year;
}
 class DateUse{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Date date = new Date();
   date.day = 15;
  System.out.println(date.day);
  }
}
```

I am using Linux terminal to compile my .java code :

```
javac Date.java
```

In Windows environment any IDE would compile without any error ,why it is giving me errors in Linux ?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Have you declared "Date" as your main class?

Comment: The exception in your title is not a compilation error. What version of Java are you using on Linux and what version are you using on Windows?

Comment: the Java version in Linux is - 1.6.0_27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you tried to run `Date` instead of `DateUse`:

```
$ javac Date.java

$ java Date
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

$ java DateUse
15
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `DateUse` a public class, and make it before the `Date` class.

Save the file as `DateUse.java` and compile it with

```
javac DateUse.java
```

The `DateUse` class contains the main method, not `Date`.

Comment: You could always merge the two classes, though.

Comment: No problem. Consider marking it as an answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method needs to be in the Date class as your file name represents the class name. Your code should be as follows:

```
public class Date{
     public byte day;
     public byte month;
     public short year;

     public static void main(String[] args){

       Date date = new Date();
       date.day = 15;
       System.out.println(date.day); 
     }
```

}

Comment: actualy it was that i was calling the wrong class - Date ,and i should call DateUse.